# Downloading (a batch of) files directly to AWS s3 bucket from url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using use an API (https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/OpenSearchAPI) to download a large number (100+) of large files (~5GB each) and I want to store these files on an AWS s3 bucket.

My first iteration was to download the files locally and use AWS CLI to move them to an S3 bucket: `aws s3 cp <local file> s3://<mybucket>`, and this works.
To avoid downloading locally I used an ec2 instance and basically did the same from there. The problem however is that the files are quite large so I'd prefer to not even have to store the files and use my ec2 instance to kind of stream the files to my S3 bucket.

Is this possible?

Comment: AWS S3 SDKs support streaming, if you're prepared to write a little code.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a byte array to populate an Amazon S3 bucket. For example, assume you are using the AWS SDK for Java V2. You can put an object into a bucket like this:

```
  PutObjectRequest putOb = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .metadata(metadata)
                    .build();


            PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(putOb,
                    RequestBody.fromBytes(getObjectFile(objectPath)));
```

Notice RequestBody.fromBytes method. Full example here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/PutObject.java

One thing to note however. If your files are really large, you may want to consider uploading in parts. See this example:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/S3ObjectOperations.java